# Is UnhandledException works properly in all cases on Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

In my Windows Phone app I use `Application.UnhandledException` to catch all unhandled errors. If that kind of error happens then my app shows a simple `MessageBox` with a request to send an error report to developers via email. It looks like this:

```
protected virtual void OnUnhandledException(
    object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            var result = MessageBox.Show(
                "Would you like to send a report to developers?", 
                "Error", 
                MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);

            if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
            {
                var task = new EmailComposeTask();
                task.To = "feedback@site.com";
                task.Subject = "Error";
                task.Body = 
                    e.ExceptionObject + "\n" + e.ExceptionObject.StackTrace;
                task.Show();

                e.Handled = true;
            }
        });
}
```

In most cases all works fine.

But many users complains that sometimes the app simply crashes with no messages. I have some crash reports in my [developer's dashboard](https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/dashboard) but these reports have a very small amount of useful information. And I can't understand what kind of error can cause this. I only have an assumption that some error happens in one of background threads.

Is `Application.UnhandledException` works properly in all cases? Could some exceptions stay unhandled? What can be done in situation described above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to the points in the other answers, you can't guarantee the Dispatcher is still running or that the UI thread will execute again.

Of course any attempt to do almost anything could fail if the app or OS is in a bad state (especially with OutOfMemory). So the less you do the better - that way you won't mess up the crash reports that the phone collects and uploads to the Store.

You should instead write the exception detail to `IsolatedStorage` and detect the presence of a past exception the next time you start your app.

Comment: Why you said that my code cannot guarantee to be in the UI thread in the exception handler? I use `Dispatcher` to do all work in the UI thread. Is it not enough? Or not correct? And thanks for the last suggestion about saving exceptions. I had a similar thoughts.

Comment: Ah, missed that. However your app should have shut down before the message appeared to the user.

Answer (score 2):

Unhandled exceptions in worker threads or those scheduled by Task are not reported in the Application.UnhandledException, AFAIK.

Have a read at this: http://www.markermetro.com/2013/01/technical/handling-unhandled-exceptions-with-asyncawait-on-windows-8-and-windows-phone-8/, there seems to be a good approach to making sure you can catch  those unhandled in async code.

Comment: Unhandled exceptions in worker threads are reported (unless you hide them with crashes in `OnUnhandledException` itself). Exceptions in tasks which are awaited ARE reported. However (as your link points out) exceptions in tasks which are not awaited (or "observed") are masked - hence the need for `TaskUnobserved_Exception`.

Answer (score 1):

Not all exceptions can be handled. Basically, all exceptions that may endanger the runtime stability won't be handled. By my experience, the most frequent one is the OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: Fortunately I have no reports about `OutOfMemoryException` in the developer's dashboard. Almost all reports point on `NullReferenceException`, `InvalidOperationException`, `TargetInvocationException`.