# How I can handle exception when it caused if I am not in debugging

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-debugging, unhandled-exception

My Windows Phone 8.1 application is unexpectedly closing when it starts. I cannot find exception because application is closing when I am not in debugging mode. When VS is attached to phone's app process - no problems, no exceptions...
Any idea please?
Moreover - this is floating bug...

Comment: After unexpected closed app, when app is starting, Previous State is - Not Running

Comment: Please show some code that probably causing the error. The problem may be in App.xaml.cs code.

Comment: If I knew where this is going, I would put the code here... Is there in WP application place, which is working when app is crashing? I want add some logging there

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is UnhandledException works properly in all cases on Windows Phone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18019040/is-unhandledexception-works-properly-in-all-cases-on-windows-phone)

Comment: And http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Reporting_unhandled_exceptions_in_your_Windows_Phone_apps